# How to decipher the structure of this mysql data?

Tags: mysql, structure, e-commerce, payment-gateway

I have this mysql data field:

```
a:3:{s:13:"bank_transfer";a:5:{s:13:"orders_prefix";s:2:"BT";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";s:9:"long_name";s:13:"Bank transfer";s:9:"surcharge";s:1:"0";s:13:"email_message";s:13:"Bank transfer";}s:16:"cash_on_delivery";a:5:{s:13:"orders_prefix";s:3:"COD";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";s:9:"long_name";s:16:"Cash on delivery";s:9:"surcharge";s:1:"6";s:13:"email_message";s:16:"Cash on delivery";}s:6:"paypal";a:10:{s:13:"orders_prefix";s:6:"PAYPAL";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";s:9:"long_name";s:21:"Paypal / Credit cards";s:9:"surcharge";s:1:"0";s:13:"currency_code";s:3:"USD";s:6:"region";s:2:"US";s:7:"sendbox";s:1:"1";s:5:"email";s:26:"californiadriven@gmail.com";s:13:"payment_limit";s:4:"8000";s:13:"email_message";s:20:"Credit Card / Paypal";}}
```

That I need to modify to include authorize.net payment method.  Anyone know what kind of structure/format or w/e the above data is?

Answer (score 0):

Nvm i figured it out:

a:# - is for number of array elements.
s:# - is for number of string characters.